# Adding portlet to control panel programmatically

Tags: liferay

I want to add my custom portlet to control panel programmatically. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably already know which portlet to make available in ControlPanel (there is only a limited number of portlets you write, right?) you don't need to make it fully programmatic, but can actually declare it like any other ControlPanel Portlet you have. (see your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067813/administrative-portlets-eg-wiki-admin-message-boards-admin-in-liferay) for information)

However, in order to make your administrative portlet to appear/disappear based on dynamic information, you can use the declaration of this element (taken from http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_0_0.dtd)

```
<!--
The control-panel-entry-class value must be a class that implements
com.liferay.portlet.ControlPanelEntry and is called by the Control Panel to
decide whether the portlet should be shown to a specific user in a specific
context. The default value is set in portal.properties.

See:

http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/portal-service/com/liferay/portlet/ControlPanelEntry.html
-->
<!ELEMENT control-panel-entry-class (#PCDATA)>
```

Comment: Nice explanation, I failed to see it from this point of view (_As you probably already know which portlet to make available in ControlPanel_). So for control panel it is actually not required to "add" it programmatically rather it should be to show/hide it programmatically. Well, for the end-user I don't think it would make any difference. I would have marked this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is **programmatically not-possible**, since:

1. The portlets on Control Panel page are not stored in database as is the case for other pages in the portal in which the portlets are stored as `typeSettings` in the `Layout` table.
2. Instead the portlets that go on the control-panel page are determined by the value of the field `_controlPanelEntryCategory` in `PortletImpl` which denotes the value of tag [`<control-panel-entry-category>`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/WEB-INF/liferay-portlet.xml#L10) in `liferay-portlet.xml` and this value is set for each portlet by the [`PortletLocalServiceImpl#_readLiferayPortletXML`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/service/impl/PortletLocalServiceImpl.java#L1312) method which I think is only called everytime either when the server starts (in [`initEAR()`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/service/impl/PortletLocalServiceImpl.java#L600)) or a portlet is deployed (in [`initWAR()`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/service/impl/PortletLocalServiceImpl.java#L691)).

So it is required to have an entry in the `liferay-portlet.xml` for the different `<control-panel-entry-*>` tags to be able to add the portlet to control panel. And this is not possible programmatically.

This is as per my reasoning and understanding, but I would like to hear from Liferay masters if this is at all possible.