# Administrative portlets (eg. Wiki Admin, Message Boards Admin) in Liferay

Tags: liferay

How can I create administrative portlet for my custom portlet, such as Wiki Admin for Wiki portlet in Liferay. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Admin portlets are not something different then other portlets in the sense that they are just new portlets which re-use some of the functionality (service methods and some JSPs) of their counter-parts and add more functionalities for Administrator like add/edit/delete/assign-roles/assign-permissions/configurations etc.

So I think you just need to create a `MyCustomAdmin` portlet for your `MyCustom` portlet in the same WAR.

If you want the `MyCustomAdmin` portlet to appear in the control-panel then you can follow the [steps here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066674/how-to-add-custom-portlet-in-control-panel-section).

It just depends upon how you design your portlet so that you can re-use stuff to-fro between the two portlets.

I hope I have answered what you desired, if you have something else in mind then kindly update the question.

<sub>**P.S.:** I assume you are talking about custom **plugin-portlets** built using plugins-SDK</sub>